# Equivalent to setting html and body height to window height in vanillajs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the equivalent code in vanilla js to this line of javascript?

```
$('html, body, #wrapper').height($(window).height());
```

This was my attempt, but it doesn't seem to be working properly (it seems to not set any height on all 3 elements at all):

```
var w=window,d=document,
    e=d.documentElement,
    g=d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    x=w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
    document.querySelector("html").clientHeight = g.clientHeight = document.getElementById("wrapper").clientHeight = y;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the height of the window using [Window#innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight), select the target using [Document#querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). To iterate the `elementList` that `querySelectorAll` returns, we'll use [NodeList#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) (if not supported convert the element list to an array - see below), and set the height on each element:

```js
var height = window.innerHeight + 'px';

document.querySelectorAll('html, body, #wrapper').forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.height = height;
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

If you need to convert the the element list to an array:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('html, body, #wrapper'), 0)
```

or

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('html, body, #wrapper'))
```