# How to scroll to the vertical center of targeted html sections with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble converting this code to vanilla js that works on iOS 11, Safari, Chrome and FF with the same behaviour. The main problem I have is getting the offsetUnit which is helping me get the scroll to the center of the section so that the text displays in the middle of the window.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var offsetUnit = $(window).height() * 0.5;
  $('html, body').scrollTop($($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top+offsetUnit);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section > div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#treatments">Treatments</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#prices">Prices</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section id="about"><div>About</div></section>
<section id="treatments"><div>Treatments</div></section>
<section id="prices"><div>Prices</div></section>
<section id="contact"><div>Contact</div></section>
```

**Current unsuccessful attempt in vanilla js**

```
function scrollPlease(element) {  
  const offsetUnit = (window.innerHeight + "px") * 0.5;
  window.scrollTo({
    'top': element.offsetTop + offsetUnit
  });
}

const link = document.querySelectorAll("[href='href_value']");
const section = document.querySelectorAll("section");

link.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollPlease(section);
});
```

https://codepen.io/2ne/pen/JmXPLB?editors=1010 - Link to codepen

Comment: What is the problem with offsetUnit? are you getting a different value then expected? or is it undefined? And what is the vanillajs code that you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent to setting html and body height to window height in vanillajs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733666/equivalent-to-setting-html-and-body-height-to-window-height-in-vanillajs)

Comment: Show us what you tried. Without it, your question is a task, a request for coding services, which makes it quite off-topic on this website.

Comment: That question does not answer how to get 50% of the height of the viewport that is the equilevent to 50vh units within css. It also does not handle how iOS 11 handles the height of the viewport. Not duplicate.

Comment: Sorry I should have posted my attempt but I didn’t want to lead the answers by following my failed methods. I will post my attempt shortly. Thanks

Comment: It's quite alright. The idea is to allow you to ask questions here, and not allow your boss or client to do it, which would work well against your interest. Another criteria is your question should be general enough so others could benefit from its answer(s). Helping one user at a time makes less sense than helping 10, 100 or even 1k at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting `offsetUnit` to a string and then trying to manipulate it as a number which won't work. In addition, you need to attach your event listeners to each link (you can't attach listeners to a collection in the way that you do it with jQuery). You aren't specifying which `section` to scroll to in your js the way you are in the jQuery original (instead you are just passing a collection of all `section` elements to your function). Corrected example below with comments (clean example in working snippet that follows):

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
const offsetUnit = window.innerHeight * 0.5;

// the "elems" variable below and the commented loop in the listener code mimic the original jquery scroll positioning
// const elems = document.querySelectorAll('html, body');

for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const section = document.querySelector(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href'));
    window.scrollTo(0, section.offsetTop + offsetUnit);
    
    // the loop below mimics the original jquery (same outcome as window.scrollTo above)
    // for (const elem of elems) {
    //   elem.scrollTop = section.offsetTop + offsetUnit;
    // }
    
  });
}
```

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
const offsetUnit = window.innerHeight * 0.5;
for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let section = document.querySelector(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href'));
    window.scrollTo(0, section.offsetTop + offsetUnit);
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section > div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#treatments">Treatments</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#prices">Prices</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id="about">
  <div>About</div>
</section>
<section id="treatments">
  <div>Treatments</div>
</section>
<section id="prices">
  <div>Prices</div>
</section>
<section id="contact">
  <div>Contact</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ah ok so my code was not even working at all? It was just using the native target behavior?

Comment: @2ne - you got it

Comment: Microsoft Edge v42 gives me a syntax error and the code doesn't work. Any ideas? "var section = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute('href'));"

Comment: @2ne what is the syntax error you are getting? It isn't working for me in Edge either but I am not seeing the syntax error because the sandboxed iframe security warnings are blocking everything in the snippet (and fiddle and pen). I will spin it up outside a snippet, take a look, and let you know what I find.

Comment: @2ne - works in Edge now with a minor edit to the answer. Had to change `scrollTo` to use coordinates instead of options for some reason (even though [browser compatibility chart shows it is supported in Edge and even IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo#Browser_Compatibility)).

Comment: Thanks for fixing it so quickly. Edge is the most overrated browser in the world. Wish M$ would have just called it a day after IE11 :)

Comment: Can you see any reason that I may get this error when trying to click the contact link, I get it in Chrome more often than Safari but I do still get it there too occasionally - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null

Comment: @2ne - could be that the click event is sometimes registering on the `li` wrapper element instead of the `a` tag. If that is the cause, then you could resolve it by changing `e.target` to `e.currentTarget` (which always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached). Probably a better approach all around with this html markup (answer edited accordingly).